# График напряжённости четырёхполюсной электрической машины

Tags: matlab

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку в формуле:
необходимо построить график напряжённости магнитного поля дипольно-квадрупольного источника (это четырёхполюсная машина, которая содержит дипольную и квадрупольную сферические гармоники поля). Внешнее магнитное поле такой машины является суммой дипольной и квадрупольной гармоник, а именно:

```
H=((R0/R)^3)*a11*cos(f)*sin(q) + ((R0/R)^4)*a22*cos(2*f)*(sin(q)^2)

R0=1;  R1=2; a11=500/1.5;  a22=1000/1.5;
g=0:0.1:2*pi;  q=0:0.1:2*pi;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(f,q);
H=((R0/R)^3)*a11*cos(f.)*sin(q.) + ((R0/R)^4)*a22*cos(2*f.)*(sin(q.)^2);
plot(X,Y,H);
```

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Вы бы хоть описали, что хотели получить и что не получилось, в чем собственно проблема? Матлаб выдает какие-то ошибки или результат вычислений неверный? Или вы думаете, что все каждый день делают такие расчеты? Да я даже не помню, что это такое (хотя и догадываюсь) и приходилось ли мне с этим сталкиваться. Матлаба под рукой нет (и вообще я его уже полгода не запускал), на вскидку вообще не могу понять, что вы делаете:

```
%тут все ясно, задаете значения по умолчанию
R0=1;
R1=2;
a11=500/1.5;
a22=1000/1.5;
g=0:0.1:2pi;
q=0:0.1:2pi;

[X,Y]=meshgrid(f,q);%это тоже понятно - делаете прямоугольную сетку

H=((R0/R)^3)a11cos(f.)sin(q.) + ((R0/R)^4)a22cos(2f.)*(sin(q.)^2);
```

А вот тут уже какой-то треш пошел, допустим, вы попропускали ряд знаков *, но что такое cos(f.)sin(q.)? Подозреваю, что cos(f).*sin(q), т.е. поэлементное умножение, угадал? Предположим, что вторая точка - это поэлементное сложение, оно не нужно, ибо сложение матриц поэлементно по определению, равно как и всяческие синусы-косинусы. Заметьте, что H у вас будет той же размерности, что и f, с, q, т.е. вектор 1хN (или Nx1, g=0:0.1:2pi в разных версиях Матлаба дает то строку, то столбец). Рискну предположить, что тут должны были использоваться не q и f, а X и Y и в итоге вы бы получили матрицу NxN

```
plot(X,Y,H);
```

А вот тут уже совсем  интересно, что, собственно, получить-то хотели? plot не умеет работать с 3D, есть plot3 для линий в 3D, и принимает он вектора по трем координатам (или матрицы, но тогда по каждой колонке строит отдельный график). Но у вас-то явно поверхность должна быть, значит, использовать надо не plot3, а что-то, что поверхность строит, скорее всего, surf.